# consultar ultimo registro de cada usuario

Tags: sql

A ver si alguien me puede echar una mano que estoy atascado

Tengo una base de datos de fichaje

Tengo dos tablas, una de `usuarios` y otra de `registros` con una llave en común que es `id_usuario`

la de usuarios tiene las siguientes tablas

```
id_usuario, nombre, apellidos
```

y la de registros lo siguiente

```
id_usuario, fecha_hora, tipo
```

en la tabla de registro se guarda todos los registros tanto de entrada como de salida de los usuarios, lo que quiero es que me muestre el último registro de cada usuario, es decir, que me muestre el ultimo registro de entrada o salida de cada usuario

Yo he consultado lo siguiente pero me muestra todos los registros de todos los usuarios

```
select usuarios.id_usuario, usuarios.nombre, registros.fecha_hora from usuarios, registros where usuarios.id_usuario = registros.id_usuario
```

Muchas gracias

Un cordial saludo

Answer (score 1):

Este el tipo de problema que uno siempre espera poder resolver con un *query* trivial, pero es un poco más complicado de lo que parece.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111384/sql-join-selecting-the-last-records-in-a-one-to-many-relationship

Lo estándar es resolverlo de una de estas maneras: obteniendo el último `registro` con un subquery para hacer un `JOIN` de las dos tablas restringido a ese `registro`, o con dos `JOIN` con la tabla `registros` y las condiciones adecuadas.

En el primer caso, haríamos algo así:

```
SELECT u.*, r2.*
FROM   usuarios u
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT   id_usuario, MAX(fecha_hora) AS maxfh
    FROM     registros
    GROUP BY id_usuario
) r1 ON u.id_usuario = r1.id_usuario
LEFT JOIN registros r2
ON        u.id_usuario = r2.id_usuario
AND       r2.fecha_hora = r1.maxfh
```

En el segundo caso, con dos `JOIN`s con la tabla `registros`, nos basamos en que para un mismo usuario, para todas las filas de `registros` vamos a poder encontrar otra fila con un valor superior de `fecha_hora`, excepto para el último `registro`, que es el que estamos buscando:

```
SELECT u.*, r1.*
FROM   usuarios u
LEFT JOIN registros r1 ON  r1.id_usuario = u.id_usuario
LEFT JOIN registros r2 ON  r2.id_usuario = u.id_usuario
                       AND r2.fecha_hora > r1.fecha_hora
WHERE r2.fecha_hora IS NULL
```

Si no lo ves muy claro, puedes ver los resultados de este *query* para comprenderlo mejor (`IDUSU` es el id de algún usuario en concreto):

```
SELECT    *
FROM      registros r1
LEFT JOIN registros r2 ON  r1.id_usuario = r2.id_usuario
                       AND r2.fecha_hora > r1.fecha_hora 
WHERE     r1.id_usuario = IDUSU
```

En todo lo anterior doy por sentado que en la tabla `registros` la tupla *(id_usuario, fecha_hora)* no se puede repetir.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes valerte de la función de ventana [`row_number()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) para numerar los registros de cada usuario (clausula `partition`), en orden de fecha descendente (clausula `order by`) y luego filtrar solamente los registros con número 1 (que serán el último registro de cada usuario).

Por ejemplo, utilizando un CTE para realizar la primera operación, en código podría lucir así:

```
;with
registro_orden as (
select   u.id_usuario
       , u.Nombre
       , u.apellidos
       , r.fecha_hora
       , r.tipo
       , row_number() over (partition by r.id_usuario order by r.fecha_hora desc) NumRegistro
  from usuarios u
       inner join registros r on r.id_usuario = u.id_usuario
)
select *
  from registro_orden
 where NumRegistro = 1;
```